# Find the constant C given Joint PDF

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I just want to ask part(a). My attempt is find the x and y first, which means 0<=x<= $\sqrt{R^2-y^2}$, and 0<=y<= $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$. And base on this observation, do the double integration. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a), note that
$$
1=\int_{D}c\,dA=c\int_{D}\,dA=c\text{Area}(D)
$$
where $D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq R^2\}$. The area of a disk is well known.

Comment: I think it is 1/R^2pi, am I correct?

Comment: Moreover, would you please give me some hint for part(b)? thx